# Problem using explode inside add_shortcode() callback funciton

Tags: php, shortcode

Explode not working as i expect inside add_shortcode() callback funciton.

**Here is the scenario:**

My implemented sortcode is like this:

```
[table]
    name1 = value1;
    name2 = value2;
    name3 = value3
[/table]
```

Which I make table using simple explode. Exploding `;` to get each row then exploding `=` to put them in right column. But explode is not working right. It exploding the whitespace after `"`, `-` and so on. I have tested the function outside wordpress to check if it have problem working with string but it works fine.

Here is page where you see the table http://computercarebd.com/?product=dell-inspiron-4030 When you look at the table you will see the **Display** row is got broken (made another array element by `explode();`) after **14.0″**

And here is the shortcode for it http://pastebin.com/ZYuuNb11

When you check the [homepage](http://computercarebd.com/) you will see the features i have added on the product preview where i used the same method but its working fine. I have used `get_the_content()` to get the content then used the same explode method.

So, i believe I have to modify the contents on the the table_shortcode() callback function to make it work with explode.

Thanks and let me know if i was clear enough.

```
function table_shortcode($atts, $content = NULL){
    $content = strip_tags($content);
    $contents = explode(';', $content);
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('width' => '370px', 'align' => 'alignright'), $atts));

    $table = '<div class="table '.$align.'" style="width:'.$width.';">';
    foreach($contents as $content){
        if(!empty($content)){
            $table .= '<div class="table_row">';
                $row_items = explode('=', $content);
                $table .= '<div class="table_left">'.(trim($row_items[0])).'</div>';
                $table .= '<div class="table_right">'.(trim($row_items[1])).'</div>';
                $table .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
            $table .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    $table .= '</div>';
    return $table;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Please add sample output and what is wrong with it to the question, I don't really get what explode is doing wrong (seemingly nothing).

Comment: @Rarst Check the table link i gave

Comment: Does any filter gets applied on the content of shortcode before it goes to the callback funciton? And also firstly i suspect that special characters might broken the table `&nbsp;`, `&amp;` as those has `;` but this is not the case as i checked the function with other character to explode (`#`);

Comment: This explodes on `;` as you specified, the issue is that HTML-encoded entities have `;` in them. Nothing WP-specific here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go with more complex characters for explode used `{@}`. As rarst said an using `;` for exploding not a good idea because html encoded entities have `;` on them.